# Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: 2013, powershell

I am getting below error while running below command for SharePoint url from powershell.

Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri http://spurl

> Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.

Comment: Do we need to add Headers? I am getting 401 error for: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "DownloadURL" -OutFile "LocalPath" -Credential $cred`

Answer (score 2):

It's a late answer, but i hope this can help someone else with the same problem:

```
        $username = "your domain/username"
        $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "your password" -AsPlainText -Force
        $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
        Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri http://spurl
```